# Em qual ordem uma classe herda de suas superclasses em python?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, python-3.x, classes, herança

Seja o código abaixo:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c  = 16
    def y(self):
        print("B.y")
    def get_c(self):
        return self.c

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 5
    def y(self):
        print("C.y")
    def get_c(self):
        return self.c

class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self):
        C.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)

var = D()
```

Ao chamar `var.y()` o resultado é `C.y`  pois `D(C, B)` herda seus métodos de suas superclasses seguindo uma ordem de esquerda para a direita. Porém, ao chamar var.get_c() o resultado é 16. Por que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) acerca de classes em Python, vemos no item de heranças múltiplas a definição:

> For most purposes, in the simplest cases, you can think of the search for attributes inherited from a parent class as depth-first, left-to-right, not searching twice in the same class where there is an overlap in the hierarchy.

Ou seja, utilizando seu exemplo, se um método/atributo não é encontrado na classe `D`, Python irá buscar por sua definição na classe `C`, primeira à esquerda. Se não encontrar, iria mais fundo, para as classes base de `C`. Como não possui, volta à classe `B` e, se não achar, vai para a classe `A`, se não achar, para as classes bases de `A`. Se ainda não achar a definição, dispara a exceção.

Portanto, quando executado `var.y()`, busca-se a definição de `y` em `D, C, B, A`, nesta ordem. Encontra em `C`, portanto retorna `C.y`. Quando executado `var.get_c()`, a mesma coisa, também é encontrado em `C`, retornando o valor de `self.c`, porém, o que acontece aqui é que no inicializador da classe `D`, você executa o inicializar da classe `B` após a da classe `C` e em ambos a propriedade `self.c` é definida. Ou seja, quando executado `C.__init__()`, o valor de `self.c` será 5, mas quando executado `B.__init__()`, o valor de `self.c` passa a ser 16, o que explica o fato de `var.get_c()` retornar o valor 16-